# Changing values of a div based on link id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've been researching this question for couple of days but couldn't find a reasonable answer anywhere.

I have 150 links and a div that appears whenever the link is clicked. The div has following values:

```
    <div id="container">
                <div class="profile pic"><img src=xx.jpg</div>
                <div class="bio">bio</div>
                <div class="profilename"><h1>name</h1></div>
                <div class="works">
                    <div class="work firstwork"></div>
                    <div class="work secondwork"></div>
                    <div class="work thirdwork"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="socialicons">
                    <a href="xx.com">icon</a>
                    <a href="xy.com">icon</a>
                    <a href="yy.com">icon</a>

                </div>
            </div>
```

So as you can see essentially it is a user profile. What I need to do is based on first links id, which is going to be:

id="FirstnameLastname"

change the contents of each child div of container div. I have the contents but what I can't figure out is what should I do in order to pull the contents in the parent child divs when a link has been clicked.

There are 10 variables for each profile so 10x15=1500.

Any ideas?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not changing the contents based on the link id, you've retrieved the data already based on the link id and now you want to put that data into the various divs.  You can start by selecting the container once, and using that as a scope in further jQuery selectors.

```
var mydata = doSomthingToGetTheJson(someLinkId);
var container = $('#container);
$('.bio', container).text(mydata.bio);
$('.profilename > h1', container).text(mydata.name);
```

and so on.

Scoping your selectors makes them faster, because you are traversing a much smaller part of the DOM tree, and helps to make sure you're not accidentally selecting nodes with the same classes from some other part of the page.

Of course you can do fancier things that just set the `.text()` content of what you selected.

I would also change some of those classes to ids instead, for example if there is only one profile name in the page, it *is* **the** `<div id="profilename">` maybe keep the class also if you prefer it for stylesheets `<div id="profilename" class="profilename">`

Comment: So how do I setup the json structure and retrieve the data from it?

Comment: @kokozz I assumed you already had that, since you marked the question `json` and said *"I have the contents but..."* -- see the jQuery documentation for [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and also $.get() $.ajax() etc. Then ask a new question if you need help with it.

Comment: Ok thanks, at least I have some checkpoint from which to keep on researching. Thanks! (: